# Using ORMLite with Google App Engine - Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, ormlite

I'm playing around with GAE Cloud SQL and trying to use it in combination with ORMLite.

Currently I'm making the connection to the database like this:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://" + instanceName + "/" + databaseName);
```

But ORMLite uses a ***ConnectionSource***, something like this:

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);

// instantiate the dao
Dao<SomeClass, String> accountDao =
            DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, SomeClass.class);
```

Now I'm not sure that this will work on GAE in production if I set the connectionSource to:

```
dbc:google:rdbms://" + instanceName + "/" + databaseName
```

Has anyone used ORMLite in combination with GAE Cloud SQL ... or is there any other way to connect ORMLite and GAE?

Comment: OK ... I have done some simple tests and couldn't get it to work on GAE (locally working just fine). Switched to hibernate and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to pass the connection you manually created before:

```
JdbcSingleConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcSingleConnectionSource("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/yourdb?user=root", connection);
connectionSource.initialize();
```

The URL doesn't really matter as long as you create the connection correctly

I know this question is ages old, but i couldnt find the answer anywhere else so I figured it could still help some people

Comment: True ages passed since I had this issue ... but still it might be helpful for someone else.